# How to get a Stream from a float[]

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was learning how to use java 8 streams when I noticed something weird.

`Arrays.stream()` has methods for everything but float arrays :

- `Arrays.stream(int[]) : IntStream`
- `Arrays.stream(long[]) : LongStream`
- `Arrays.stream(double[]) : DoubleStream`

Similarly, there are Stream implementations for int, double etc but not floats :

- `IntStream`
- `LongStream`
- `DoubleStream`

Is there a reason for that?

what is the recommended way to work with float streams?

Comment: I was under the impression that they just support the most common primitive types out-of-the-box, but I'm not sure. Maybe you can have a look at the source code and come up with a FloatStream and a stream(float[]): FloatStream method?

Comment: from 'Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient' : "If you want to store short, char, byte, and boolean, use an IntStream, and for float, use a DoubleStream. The library designers didn’t think it was worth adding another five stream types."

Comment: @marcin_j your comment is worth an answer. Post it and I will accept it.

Comment: Probably because there's no real good reason to use `float` at all, for anything.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

from `Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient` by Cay S. Horstmann :

> 2.12. Primitive Type Streams
>
> ... If you want to store short, char, byte, and boolean, use an
>   IntStream, and for float, use a DoubleStream. The library designers
>   didn’t think it was worth adding another five stream types.

Comment: tbh, I'd rather use a Stream<Character> than to use an intStream and have to cast int to char every single time I want to do anything with it.

Answer (score 57):

Here's a better way, that doesn't involve copying the data.

```
DoubleStream ds = IntStream.range(0, floatArray.length)
                           .mapToDouble(i -> floatArray[i]);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Comment: It's so confusing that it uses a IntStream :)

Comment: to convert from short array to IntStream

`IntStream is = IntStream.range(0, shortValues.length).map(i -> shortValues[i]);`

Comment: the most elegant solution I've seen so far...
I would add: `` return ds.toArray();``

Comment: but wouldn't the toArray() method return a double array instead of a float one? That case would help for traversing through an float array, but doesn't help much if you need a float array as stream output.

Answer (score 3):

I asked myself this question. To answer it, I began working on a library that included things like FloatToIntFunction and ByteToCharFunction and (of course) FloatStream,CharStream,ByteStream,etc. It quickly became a headache for me.

It would have been a LOT of work on the part of the library developers to do this because you'd have to create methods and interfaces to to between ALL of the primitive data types. As you implement more data types, it becomes a bigger and bigger mess. Imagine having to implement methods to go from float to all the other primitive types, double to all the other primitive types, char to all the other primitive types, etc.

The long term solution for this is for Java to add value types so that you can do things like `Stream<int>` and `Stream<float>` rather than using wrapper types (`Stream<Integer>` and `Stream<Float>`)

Take a look at Project Vahalla for updates on this feature which may be added to Java in the future.
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/