# Java stream to float array?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have a file where each line is a pipe-delimitted string of float values. 
I am reading the file line by line and splitting by "|" and then casting each element to a float. I can use Java streams to get this as a Float array, but I want to know if it is possible to get this as the primitive float[] array. The reason being is that I am passing these values into a library which expects float[].

Here is my code:

```
br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFile));
String[] lines = br.lines().toArray(String[]::new);

for(String line : lines) {
    Float[] inputs = 
             Arrays.stream(line.split("|"))
                   .map((x) -> Float.parseFloat(x))
                   .toArray(Float[]::new);
}
```

Is there a way to use streams to get a primitive float[] array, or do I still need to iterate over the Float[] and convert? I looked into DoubleStream, but I can't have a double[].

Thanks

**EDIT: thanks for all comments. Ended up iterating over Float[] and calling .floatValue on each element and storing the value in a float[].**

Comment: And not with `Float`. You can `mapToDouble` and then `toArray`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis forgot to escape it when typing here. it is escaped in my code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis mapToDouble still gives me a double array, unless there is a way to get it to give me a float[]. if so, please show.

Comment: @JimGarrison won't that give me a double[]? I need float[]. I could then just do toArray(float[])?

Comment: "[..] not with `Float`" You'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am not able to use primitive float[] in List.toArray. Do you have an example of that? I tried: Float[] inputs = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\|")).map((x) -> Float.parseFloat(x)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(float[]);

Comment: @Seephor there's _not_ going to be a good way of doing this other than by hand.  No built in utility will help.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26970398/2711488) is a Stream based solution for collecting a `DoubleStream` into a `float[]` array. All you have to change in your code to use it, is to replace `.map((x) -> Float.parseFloat(x))` with `.mapToDouble(Float::parseFloat)` to create a `DoubleStream` (so the `float` gets temporarily promoted to `double`, but it should stay in the defined value set).