# How can I convert an ArrayList of floats to a primitive float array using java 8 streams?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-8

I'm trying to convert an `ArrayList` containing `float` values to an array of primitive floats using the Java 8 Stream API. 
What I tried so far looked something like this:

```
List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<Float>(); 
float[] floatArray = floatList.stream().map(i -> i).toArray(float[]::new)
```

Comment: So what the problem is?

Comment: If a `double[]` is sufficient you can use `floatList.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).toArray();`. `float` is a bit of an archaic type.

Comment: Since they didn't add a `FloatStream`, only a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html), you can only do this by writing your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

Comment: Not a dup, but related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970398/2711488

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly: there's no good built-in way to do this with streams.  Sorry, but it's the truth.

If you can live with a `double[]`, you can use `floatList.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).toArray()`, but that's probably not what you're hoping for.

If you want to do it with streams, you'll need to write your own custom resizing list type and collect to it, but nothing short of that is going to work.  You'd have to write something like

```
float[] toFloatArray(Collection<Float> collection) {
  class FloatArray {
    int size;
    float[] array;
    FloatArray() {
      this.size = 0;
      this.array = new float[10];
    }
    void add(float f) {
      if (size == array.length) {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);
      }
      array[size++] = f;
    }
    FloatArray combine(FloatArray other) {
      float[] resultArray = new float[array.length + other.array.length];
      System.arraycopy(this.array, 0, resultArray, 0, size);
      System.arraycopy(other.array, 0, resultArray, size, other.size);
      this.array = resultArray;
      this.size += other.size;
      return this;
    }
    float[] result() {
      return Arrays.copyOf(array, size);
    }
  }
  return collection.stream().collect(
     Collector.of(
         FloatArray::new, FloatArray::add, 
         FloatArray::combine, FloatArray::result));
}
```

It'd be much simpler to convert your collection directly to a `float[]` without streams, either by yourself with a straightforward loop --

```
float[] result = new float[collection.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Float f : collection) {
  result[i++] = f;
}
```

or with a third-party library, e.g. Guava's [`Floats.toArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Floats.html#toArray-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 4):

How about this? You can use [FloatBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html) to collect the `float[]`, for example:

```
float[] result = floatList.stream().collect(
  ()-> FloatBuffer.allocate(floatList.size()), 
  FloatBuffer::put,
  (left, right) -> { 
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("only be called in parallel stream");
  }
).array();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) [`Collectors2`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html) with the `Stream` `collect` method, you can accomplish this.

```
ArrayList<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>();
floats.add(new Float(1.0f));
floats.add(new Float(2.0f));
floats.add(new Float(3.0f));
float[] floatArray =
        floats.stream()
                .collect(Collectors2.collectFloat(
                                Float::floatValue,
                                FloatLists.mutable::empty))
                .toArray();
```

You can also accomplish this without using Streams by using the [`LazyIterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/LazyIterate.html) class.

```
float[] array =
    LazyIterate.adapt(floats).collectFloat(Float::floatValue).toArray();
```

If you use the built in primitive collections, you can simply convert a `FloatList` to a float array as follows:

```
float[] array = FloatLists.mutable.with(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f).toArray();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to convert an `Object[]` to a primitive array(`float []` in your case).

Alternate way possible(assuming `Nonnull` values) could be as:

```
Object[] arr = floatList.toArray();
for (Object o : arr) {
    System.out.println((float)o);
}
```

Commons from apache provides a util for it though [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[]))

Comment: You can't cast an `Object[]` to a `Float[]` it will throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: I mean, it is possible with streams, just only for `int[]`, `long[]`, and `double[]`.  And you'd have to write `floatList.toArray(new Float[0])`, you can't do that cast.