# Converting 2 dimensional ArrayList to 2 dimensional float array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-stream

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();
```

This is the arraylist I'm using.
And I tried this:

```
float[][] trainingData = lists.stream()
                        .map(l -> l.stream()
                       .mapToFloat(Float::parseFloat)
                       .toArray())
                       .toArray(float[][]::new);
```

I'm getting this error :

> The method mapToFloat(Float::parseFloat) is undefined for the type Stream

I must convert this two dimensional ArrayList into two dimensional Float array.

Comment: `lists.stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .toArray(float[][]::new);`

Comment: Can you use a `Float[][]` instead of a `float[][]`? If not, your only choice is a double for loop.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970398/2711488) contains a collector for a `float[]` array. Seeing it, you will likely realize that using a loop is simpler…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost the reason why your code doesn't work is because there's no such method `mapToFloat` in the Java API but most importantly there is no `FloatStream`.

your options are quite limited if you want to accomplish this via streams:

1. accumulate to a `Float[][]` instead of a `float[][]`, which might not be ideal as it involves boxing and unboxing bottleneck when you want to perform some computation later on in your application.

this can be accomplished via:

```
Float[][] trainingData = lists.stream()
                .map(l -> l.toArray(new Float[0]))
                .toArray(Float[][]::new);
```

2. use a `List<List<Double>>` in the first place rather than a `List<List<Float>>`to represent your training data, then you can just convert it to a `double[][]` when required:

this can be accomplished via:

```
double[][] trainingData = lists.stream()
                .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray())
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

but if you cannot change the initial type of data for whatever reasons then you can still covert to a `double[][]`.

this can be accomplished via:

```
double[][] trainingData = lists.stream()
                .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(Float::doubleValue).toArray())
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

3. define your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) which you should be able to find within the site with some research.

Ultimately you're probably better off using an imperative approach here i.e. `for` loops.

Comment: When you say “use a `List<List<Double>>` in the first place”, it’s contradicting to use `Float::doubleValue` in the example code.

Comment: @Holger I see where you're coming from but that piece of code was referring to _but if you cannot change the initial type of data for whatever reasons then you can still covert to a double[][]._. i'll try to clarify that.

Comment: So there is no example for converting `List<List<Double>>` to `double[][]`, actually. But when you change `Float::doubleValue` to `Number::doubleValue`, the code works regardless of whether the OP uses `List<List<Double>>` or `List<List<Float>>`…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Float[][] trainingData = lists
             .stream().map(lst -> lst.stream().toArray(Float[]::new))
             .toArray(Float[][]::new);
```

If you need primitive arrays, the only way I can think of is what you probably already knew (but I include for completeness).

```
float[][] trainingData = new float[lists.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    List<Float> innerList = lists.get(i);
    float[] temp = trainingData[i] = new float[innerList.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
            temp[k] = innerList.get(k);
    }
}

for(float[] v : trainingData) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
}
```

Both print

```
[10.0, 10.2]
[20.4, 2.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

For float there is no good way with stream, you can get as 2D double array this way

```
double[][] trainingData = lists.stream()
        .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).toArray()).toArray(double[][]::new);
```