# Converting an array of strings to an array of floats in java

Tags: java, arrays, types

I am trying to convert an array of strings to an array of floats in Java, is there a more elegant way to do this than going through each element of the string array with a loop and converting it to a float using  something like `Float.parseFloat(strings[i])`?

Comment: I guess you have iterate through each element of the array. And at the time using Float.parseFloat check if the element is of type Float using instanceof keyword

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if this is really **better**, but using Java 8 you could convert the array the following way:

```
String[] strings = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
Float[] floats = Arrays.stream(strings).map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

---

If you want to use `double` instead you could use the primitive type (unfortunately the steams do not provide something like `mapToFloat` or a `FLoatStream` class, see here for [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23106578/1342006)):

```
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(strings).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
```

---

**Remark:**

Please notice also the difference of using `parseDouble` versus `valueOf`:
`parseDouble` returns the primitive type, whereas `valuOf` will return the boxed type.

Comment: I guess you could've used `float[]::new` instead no?

Comment: I think valueOf will be more feasible

Comment: this will still go through each element of the string array, though its indeed more elegant

Comment: Is the `Arrays` keyword the Java 8 part? That's where my editor is throwing errors.''

Comment: @YassinHajaj: see my edit.

Comment: @Jobin: you are right, I changed it and added the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @EthanJones: it is part of the Java SDK: `java.util.Arrays`. Be sure to have the appropriate import statement on top.