# Convert Java stream of strings to array of float

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to find an elegant way to convert a `Stream<String>` to `float[]`.

Until now I've come out with:

```java
Float[] data = input.map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

But I actually need a `float[]` and when I try:

```
float[] data = input.map(x -> Float.parseFloat(x)).toArray(size -> new float[]);
```

I get an error cannot convert `Object[]` to `float[]`, which I don't really understand.

Comment: What is the element type of the `input` stream?

Comment: There's no `FloatStream`, so I don't think this is possible without writing a custom collector which converts from either `Float` or `double`.

Comment: Would a `double[]` do? If so, you could use [`Stream#mapToDouble(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) to obtain a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)

Comment: Why `float` and not `double`? Then you could use `DoubleStream`.

Comment: The duplicate is exactly not what OP wants. If anything, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297869/converting-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-java) is what OP wants. But even this does not answer the question as to why it does not work. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I would say that it is not a duplicate. I've seen that answer and it didn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: There's another answer embedded in there.  There is no way to get a primitive `float` out of a stream in this fashion.

Comment: Use `mapToDouble(Float::parseFloat)` together with the collector of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970398/2711488).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a minor error in your code, which we will fix first to reveal the larger problem at hand:

```
float[] data = input.map(x -> Float.parseFloat(x)).toArray(size -> new float[]);
```

should be:

```
float[] data = input.map(x -> Float.parseFloat(x)).toArray(size -> new float[size]);
                                                                             ^this is new
```

---

Even if it might not seem like it, your question is realted to generics. Let us take a look at the [definition of `Stream#toArray(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction):):

```
public <A> A[] toArray​(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

Since this method is generic in `A`, the type `A` must not be a primitive. You, on the other hand, try to set `A` to `float` (this is done through [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), this is why you do not see the generic parameters in your code). The compiler now complains that:

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable A has incompatible bounds
    float[] data = input.stream().map(x -> Float.parseFloat(x)).toArray(size -> new float[size]);
                                                                       ^
    equality constraints: float
    upper bounds: Object
  where A is a type-variable:
    A extends Object declared in method <A>toArray(IntFunction<A[]>)
1 error
```

---

[This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297869/converting-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-floats-in-java) provide solutions/workarounds to the problem of converting a `String`-stream to a `float[]`.

Comment: The missing size is actually a typo, in the code I have got it. I'll not fix the question or your answer will lose meaning. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is *no way* of getting `float[]` directly from any Stream in Java yet. There are "only" 3 available converting mechanisms to numeric Stream interfaces:

- [`mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) -> [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)
- [`mapToLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) -> [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html)
- [`mapToDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) -> [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)

Thus the only way is to use `double` instead, which is fairly easy:

```
double[] data = input.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
```

If you insist to get the `float[]` from `double[]`, it's another issue where might help the `Guava` library:

```
float[] floatArray = Floats.toArray(Doubles.asList(data));
// You can collect Stream to a Collection and pass directly Floats.toArray(list);
```

Or a simple `for-loop`:

```
float[] floatArray = new float[data.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
    floatArray[i] = (float) data[i];
}
```

---

Alternatively, you might use the method `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` which returns the array of an Object type. However, to unbox `Float`, you have to use the for-loop again in the very same way - it gives no difference except you can work with `Float[]` directly, although boxed.

- [`map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) -> [`Stream<R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Here is the use:

```
Float[] data = input.map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way with my library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
float[] result = Stream.of(input).mapToFloat(Float::parseFloat).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for doing what the core Java library team couldn't be arsed to do. Single Precision is handy anywhere hardware acceleration is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value from the Float Object through the floatValue() method to create a array:

```
Float[] data = input.map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
float[] primData = new float[data.length];

for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
    primData[x] = data[x].floatValue();
}
```