# How can I concatenate two float arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

Using Java 8 I am trying to concatenate two float arrays:

```
void f(float[] first, float[] second) {
    float[] both = ???
}
```

From a quick SO search, I thought I could simply follow instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java#comment76034741_23188881). So I tried:

```
float both[] = FloatStream.concat(Arrays.stream(first), Arrays.stream(second)).toArray();
```

But this does not compile as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106093/how-to-get-a-stream-from-a-float). So I tried the less efficient solution and use a `Stream` directly:

```
float[] both = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(first), Arrays.stream(second)).toArray(float[]::new);
```

It fails to compile from my eclipse saying:

```
The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments  (float[])
```

What is the most efficient (and simple) way of concatenating two `float[]` arrays in Java 8 ?

---

Update: obviously the whole point of the question is that I have to deal with `float` and not `double`.

Comment: If you can use a `double[]` instead of `float[]`, `double[] both = DoubleStream.concat(Arrays.stream(first), Arrays.stream(second)).toArray();` will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it yourself, use `System.arrayCopy()` to copy both arrays into a new array of the combined size. That's much more efficient, as it uses native OS code.

Comment: native != faster, it might be like this, but not a rule

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no `FloatStream` and even creating an (inefficient) boxed stream out of a float array is not simple, you won’t find a stream based solution that is simpler than

```
static float[] f(float[] first, float[] second) {
    float[] both = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length+second.length);
    System.arraycopy(second, 0, both, first.length, second.length);
    return both;
}
```

Even the option to use a parallel stream is unlikely to outweigh the raised complexity. You would need *really large* arrays to see a benefit.

Comment: I was about to update the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929463/1746118) with a bit longer version of the same. Nice optimization overall though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own code to do this.  The problem has already been solved and tested.  You should use the [Apache Commons `ArrayUtils` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll-float:A-float...-).

```
float[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Under the covers, it has some logic for a couple of special cases where one input or the other is null, followed by two calls to `System.arraycopy`.  But you don't need to worry about any of that.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer to the question, a oneliner which effectively solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is guava an option? since it has `Floats.concat` a bit more fluent, but it's still `System.arrayCopy` underneath.

Problem is that `jdk` does not have a `FloatStream` - that could be used here, you might return a `Float[]` from such a thing:

```
Stream.concat(
            IntStream.range(0, first.length)
                    .boxed()
                    .map(x -> first[x]),
            IntStream.range(0, first.length)
                    .boxed()
                    .map(y -> first[y]))
            .toArray(Float[]::new);
```

But that is too many operations for such a simple thing.