# why Arrays.sort() can't sort primitive type array in descending order?

Tags: java

As we know, the following code can work:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[len];
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> (b - a));
```

But why we can't do this with an int[], why java doesn't allow this?

Comment: Because the method `sort` is generic on type `T` and accepts `T[]` as parameter, but primitives like `int` cannot be a generic type, `T` cannot be `int`.

Comment: This just seems like laziness on the part of the API design. They could have made an interface for each primitive type - `IntComparator`, `ShortComparator`, `FloatComparator`, ad nauseum - and provided functions like `Arrays.sort(int[] a, IntComparator)`.

Comment: I would really love to hear why java doesn't allow sorting in descending order? Had they forget to put one or there were strong reasons to not provide descending order sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the signature of the Arrays#sort method you are trying to use

```
  public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
   ...
  }
```

Where `<T>` the class of the objects to be sorted in the Array. Primitive `int` can't be a convert class.

Comment: You are repeating what was already mentioned in the question. The OP already pointed out that you can do this with non-primitives, and is asking why you can't do the same with primitives. It's pointless, useless, and not an answer, to say that primitives can't be converted to objects.

Comment: Yes, he has mentioned that he wants to sort int[] (primitive int) in descending order but he tried to use a method which is not compatible with his parameters and I have pointed out that part.

Comment: So, why isn't there a method in Arrays.sort that does what he wants? That's what the OP is asking. Something like `public static void sort(int[] a, IntComparator c)` ? Because it could very well be there, and the OP didn't specify that he wanted to use your method. He just want to be able to call `Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> (b - a));` with `int[] arr`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the questions as phrased right now is "why does it not work using this method" - this answer and my comment answers that. Why there is no alternative method available is something for another question (if at all answer-able)

Comment: The question is very clearly "But why we can't do this with an int[], why java doesn't allow this?". That's a purely opinion based question, and should be closed because of that - but that's not the question that you answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the order induced sort method  `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` method uses comparator. As you can not parameterise a Comparator<>  with a primitive type, this method has to be used with Objects. Like in Map we can not declare `Map<int, boolean>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23106578/5784273) - the language designers have probably concluded that it would be too much, since creating the methods for all primitives would've dragged with it the need for creating corresponding comparator classes, which would've probably been useless anywhere except in this case.

So one can just sort the array in ascending order and then use the `Apache Commons Lang` to [reverse](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#reverse-int:A-) its elements:

```
int[] arr = ...
Arrays.sort(arr);
ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);
```