# Why is it not possible to cast float[] to double[] in Java?

Tags: java, types, casting

I'm using an API that returns two-dimensional `float` array as a result. I'd like to process this data using the `flatMap` method from the streaming API, but I need to pass arrays of `double`s into its methods. I've tried to work it around by casting `float[][]` into `double[][]`, but it didn't work, even with `float[]`. Here's a JShell session dump:

```
-> new float[] {1.02f, 4.32f, 65.4f}
  Expression value is: [F@2b98378d
    assigned to temporary variable $1 of type float[]

-> double[] arrayOfDoubles = (double[]) $1
  Error:
  incompatible types: float[] cannot be converted to double[]
  double[] arrayOfDoubles = (double[]) $1;
```

So, my question is: why can't we cast `float[]` into `double[]`, when it's fairly legal to cast from `float` to `double`?

Comment: Think about what needs to happen during a cast and how each of the types are stored in memory.

Comment: Why are you working with floats to begin with?

Answer (score 6):

If you were to look at the memory space inhabited by a `float[]` **as if** it were `double[]`, then the offsets into the array would be all wrong. So you would be seeing part of float #1 and float #2 when you look at double #1. That's why you need conversion, not just casting.

Put another way, the Java Language Specification simply doesn't supply such a conversion in the form of casting related syntax.

Getting back to your original problem, here is an excellent tip from [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556852/7098259):

```
DoubleStream ds = IntStream.range(0, floatArray.length)
                       .mapToDouble(i -> floatArray[i]);
```

And finally, here is your flatMap DoubleStream, via the above trick:

```
DoubleStream ds = Arrays.stream(float2dArray)
        .flatMapToDouble(floatArray -> IntStream.range(0, floatArray.length)
                .mapToDouble(i -> floatArray[i]));
```

Comment: any specific reason why IntStream.range with array accessors should be used over Arrays.stream? iirc, it had overloads for the primitive streams

Comment: @Wietlol you can stream the float[][] since each float[] is an Object, so it can use the overloaded method for Object[]. however you cannot stream the float[] because there is no overloaded method for that signature! See the linked answer of Brian (click his name above) for details on that part

Comment: ah, they just didnt add the Arrays.stream for float[], just int, long and double. makes sense... i mean to do the range then

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are reference types, even arrays with primitive elements.

Casting reference types doesn't actually *do* anything to the underlying object: it merely tells the compiler "trust me, I know more type information than you: this reference to a Foo can be safely treated as a reference to a Bar".

Unless the compiler can prove that the cast is unsafe, it trusts you and lets you do it; it is on you, the programmer, to check that it is safe, or face ClassCastExceptions at runtime.

So, casting a `float[]` to a `double[]` doesn't change the underlying object, it merely changes what the compiler lets you do with it.

But once you can treat it like a `double[]`, you can ask the JVM to assign a `double` to an element of that array. `double` doesn't fit in `float`, so there are two choices:

- Check if the value is in range, and cast. But then you lose precision, in a way that will be potentially very hard to debug;
- Or, stop you getting into the situation in the first place by preventing you assigning a `float[]` to a `double[]`.

The second choice is simpler, and that is the choice they made.

---

Note that you *can* cast a `float[]` to a `double[]`, by casting via `Object`:

```
float[] f = ...
double[] d = (double[]) (Object) f;
```

This will fail at runtime, however, unless `f` is null.