# Replacement for no Java Collectors.summingFloat()

Tags: java, java-stream

The standard Java libraries provide nice [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/Collectors.html) utils for reduction, such as `summingInt()`, `summingLong()`, and `summingDouble()`. It does not look like there is `summingFloat()`, though. Is there a suggested workaround? Or perhaps are floats discouraged for some reason?

Comment: No idea if it is a good practice or not, but you can just look at `Collectors.summing...` implementation and try to write something like that yourself. It should take 2 min.

Comment: `Or perhaps are floats discouraged for some reason?` the general advise is to stay away from them because `doubles` offer far more accucary and the extra memory required doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: though i'm not sure , but i think the reason is it's more precise to use double.

Answer (score 2):

> are floats discouraged for some reason?

Yes, they are discouraged because of the very low precision they have, as low as 6 digits (they have *"from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision"*, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)).

The extra storage needed is generally not an issue, while the lack of precision can be a huge issue, that may not present itself with small test cases, so it's safer to use `double` unless absolute necessary.

---

If the objects you're streaming have a method returning a `float`, and you want to sum the values from that method, use [`summingDouble(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) and "cast" the result back to `float` using the [`floatValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#floatValue--) method of `Double`.

```java
float sum = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(o -> o.getFloat()))
        .floatValue();
```

Comment: `summingDouble()` is preferred as it tries to improve accuracy with compensated summation.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there a suggested workaround?**

You could convert the `float` values to `double` as follows:

```
Stream.of(1F, 2F, 3F).mapToDouble(Float::doubleValue).sum();
```

Or use `reduce` to sum the `float` values (mind that this will return a `Optional<Float>` instead of the primitive type as the previous solution do):

```
Stream.of(1F, 2F, 3F).reduce(Float::sum);
```

---

> **Or perhaps are floats discouraged for some reason?**

It [looks like](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/moocjdk8/documents/week2/lesson-2-3.pdf) the reason for the existence of only 3 primitive stream types is:

> To avoid a lot of unnecessary object creation and work we have three primitive stream types

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23106578/7122251) also shows a similar reason for this.

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-primitive-streams) adds the [boxing overhead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) argument to the matter:

> Primitive streams are limited mainly because of boxing overhead and because creating specialized streams for other primitives isn't' that useful in many cases.

---

**EDIT**

As [Karol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602555/karol-dowbecki) mentioned in the comments, to avoid floating point innacuracy, you may convert it to `float` after using `sum()` from `DoubleStream`, as the first solution do:

```
float result = (float) Stream.of(1F, 2F, 3F).mapToDouble(Float::doubleValue).sum();
```

The [API reference for `sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) explains how it is different from simply reducing like `reduce(0, Double::sum)`:

> The order of addition operations of this method is intentionally not defined to allow for implementation flexibility to improve the speed and accuracy of the computed result. In particular, this method may be implemented using compensated summation or other technique to reduce the error bound in the numerical sum compared to a simple summation of double values.

Comment: reducing with `Float::sum` is not the same as compensated (Kahan) summation in Double stream `sum()`