# how to convert from float array to Float List in java

Tags: java

`Arrays.stream` does not accept primitive type float data. Is there a method to convert from `float[]` to `List<Float>`?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam It does not. The issue the OP is facing is that the JDK classes do not have `FloatStream` the OP would like it to have.

Comment: It might be implemented like this: `IntStream.range(0, array.length).mapToObj(i -> array[i]).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())` (as suggested by Brian Goetz https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556852/12232870 )

Comment: Arrays.stream() has methods for Arrays.stream(int[]) : IntStream, Arrays.stream(long[]) : LongStream, Arrays.stream(double[]) : DoubleStream. But, Arrays.stream() did not have FloatStream. Is this useful for you- https://microeducate.tech/how-to-get-a-stream-from-a-float/ ??